# Registering .ne for non-residents

Tags: domains, top-level-domains

AFAIK it's hard to register one if you aren't resident. Are there registers which can pre-register for me .ne (like NetworkSolutions does for .eu)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It looks as though they are available for registration to entities connected with Niger only. So a regular registrar won't be able to help you get one.